# Font Awesome Stacked Icon SIze

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I can't seem to change to size of the font awesome icons within a stacked set. I would like the icons to be smaller they currently are.

Do I need to create an additional css rule?

My code so far is;

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background4"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x icon-background6"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-lock fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background5"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-camera fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```

CSS

```
.icon-background4 {
    color: #c0ffc0;
}

.icon-background6 {
    color: #40c040;
}

.icon-background5 {
    color: #c0c0ff;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/aum5vbfy/1/).

Notes

- I don't want to use inline styling in the html.
- I want to outer circle to remain the same size

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you tried using font-size?

Comment: It's because your span around them have width:2em and your icons have width:100%
CLASS:
.fa-stack-2x {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

Comment: you can add class for smaller font `fa-1` `fa-2``fa-3`

Comment: In this: `<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">` the class `fa-5x` is a `font-size` multiplier...that's huge. Adjust `fa-5x` accordingly (ex. `fa-3x`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`font-awesome` icons is a font and not graphics. So it can be sized by simply using `font-size`

When you add the built-in classes, you just applies the css properties via a class.

I need  to add `!important` otherwise it doesn’t work. Maybe it could be improved but you can see how it works in the code fiddle

```css
.icon-background4 {
  color: #c0ffc0;
}

.icon-background6 {
  color: #40c040;
}

.icon-background5 {
  color: #c0c0ff;
}

.fa-camera {
  font-size: 10px;
}


/* */

.test-icon-size {
  font-size: 15px !important;
}

.test-icon-size-2 {
  font-size: 40px !important;
}

.test-icon-size-3 {
  font-size: 60px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--  v2 -->

<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background5"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-camera fa-stack-1x test-icon-size"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background5"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-camera fa-stack-1x test-icon-size-2"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background5"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-camera fa-stack-1x test-icon-size-3"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sébastien Gicquel but I'm looking to change the size of the icon *only*. I want the outer circle to remain the same size.

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek I've updated my answer. Is it better for you ? If it is the desired result, i will try to improve the code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<span class="fa-stack fa-5x">` , try fa-2x or 3x as per your requirement. If you want a default size, then completely remove fa-5x from the parent span tag.

Answer (score -1):

Try with below code.

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background4"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x icon-background6"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-lock fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>

<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background5"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-camera fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```